# How to read arabic file names inside directory

Tags: php, arabic

I am trying to read files inside directory.It works fine i am getting the list of files but the file names with arabic characters not showing just showing "???.txt?"

```
<?php
$dir = "C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures";
// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $file_utf8 = iconv( "Windows-1256", "utf-8", $file );
        echo "filename:" . $file_utf8 . "<br>";
      }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: First find out what encoding the file names inside your file system actually are. Before you are absolutely certain of that encoding there is little sense in going on.

Comment: What is your file name? @user2470312

Answer (score -1):

If you `echo` the

```
echo $dir;
```

you may find that it is not stored in `$dir` variable as expected. So you should put the string in **single quotes** (`'`) instead of **double quotes** (`"`):

```
$dir = `C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures`;
```